# Сдвиг границы таблицы при добавлении абсолютно позиционированного псевдоэлемента к <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица. Я добавляю через JS строки. К новым строкам через `::after` добавляю крестик «Delete row»; псевдоэлемент абсолютно позиционирован, однако при первом добавлении новой строки происходит сдвиг границы таблицы. Не могу понять почему, ведь псевдоэлемент `::after` абсолютно позиционирован и не должен влиять на отрисовку элементов.

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const tr = tbody.querySelector('tr:last-child').cloneNode(true);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

tr:nth-child(n + 3) {
  position: relative;
}

tr:nth-child(n + 3)::after {
  color: #f00;
  content: '×';
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: -3%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button>Add row</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qhv5n3g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... псевдоэлемент `::after` абсолютно позиционирован и не должен влиять на отрисовку элементов.

С обычными элементами это верно, но элементы таблицы могут вести себя по-другому. Например, тег `<tr>` создаёт для псевдоэлемента ещё одну ячейку (хотя её и не видно в DOM, но по тому, что отображается на странице, это именно так). Ну, а раз псевдоэлемент у Вас `position: absolute`, то и места он не занимает, но `border-spacing` по прежнему применяется даже к ячейке с нулевыми размерами.

С тегами `<th>` или `<td>` всё проще, поэтому рекомендую отталкиваться именно от них:

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const tr = tbody.querySelector('tr:last-child').cloneNode(true);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr:nth-child(n + 3) {
  position: relative;
}

tr:nth-child(n + 3) td:last-child::after {
  content: 'x';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: -3%;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button>Add row</button>
```